# where create.php needs to be located for remotely saving the pdf generated using alivepdf with flex

Tags: flex4, alivepdf

I am using alivepdf library to generate pdf with flex 4.6

While saving pdf i am using the following line

```
myPDF.save( Method.REMOTE, "http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/wp-content/demos/create.php", "inline", "drawing.pdf", "_blank" );
```

Could you please guide where to place the create.php in our server so that i dont have to use alivepdf server.
We are using Apache tomcat server 7.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can place it at the root of your server... I think it uses port 8888
so try "localhost:8888/create.php"